# iOS 14 AVPlayer not showing video, but playing sound

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, ios14

Old Objective C project that plays video and works perfectly on iOS 13 and below (and iOS 14.2 beta), but on iOS 14.0 it only plays sound from the video. The video is blank.

Any idea why this is?

I load the video like this:

```
_videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_videoPlayer];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
_videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;
playerLayer.frame = _videoContainer.bounds;

[_videoContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

[_videoContainer bringSubviewToFront:_playButton];

[_videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

`_videoContainer` is just a standard `UIView`.

Comment: Hi Johan - something else here ... I am able to do it no problem using copy and paste of your code and iOS 14.0